# Checkbox not working with Bootstrap in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a Checkbox which is not getting checked if I keep it inside the div tag

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
<label class="lbl" for="a">Fee</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<input type="checkbox" id="a" ng-model="x.y" >
</div>
```

whereas it works perfectly when I remove it from the div tag.

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
<label class="lbl" for="a">Fee</label>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="a" ng-model="x.y">
```

Why is it so? 
How can div tag affect the behavior of checkboxes.
Note: I am not using any inline style nor am I overloading any pre-defined class.

I am having this code inside an accordion (bootstrap one)in a partial view which I am calling from my main page(using ng-include tag).

EDIT: I created a JSFiddle of my code, but it is working fine in JSFiddle. Can calling it from Partial view be a problem?

JS Link: http://jsfiddle.net/gandhi_rahul/sk60mpwn/2/

Comment: Make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example...

Comment: You are self closing the first input `<input type="checkbox" id="a" ng-model="x.y">` check this

Comment: Can you replicate this issue in a Fiddle?

Comment: I have edited the post.
JS Link: http://jsfiddle.net/gandhi_rahul/sk60mpwn/2/

Comment: But it is working fine in JSFiddle. I am loading my page as partial view from main Page.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap checkbox should be set out like

```
<form>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```